# Solve ridge regression gradient over line segment

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, regularization

I want to solve the equation for ridge regression:

\begin{align}
f(\beta)=&\frac{1}{2}||X \beta-y||_2^2+\lambda_{1} \frac{1}{2}||\beta||^2_2 \\
\end{align}

Where $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \beta\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times1}, y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$.

Over a line segment

\begin{align}
(a+\gamma(s-a))
\end{align}

Where $a\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times1}, s\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times1}$

And I need to solve this for gamma. So I tried solving this as I would a scalar problem by substituting this in for $\beta$ and setting equal to $0$ as such:

\begin{align}
\nabla f(\beta)=&X^{\top}(X \beta-y)+\lambda_{1} \beta \\
\nabla f((a+\gamma(s-a)))=&X^{\top}(X(a+\gamma(s-a))-y)+\lambda_{1}(a+\gamma(s-a))\\
=&X^{\top}(X a+\gamma X(s-a)-y)+\ldots\\
=&X^{\top}Xa+\gamma X^{\top} X(s-a)-X^{\top} y+\lambda_1 a+\gamma \lambda_{1}(s-a)\\
=&\gamma\left(X^{\top} X(s-a)+\lambda_{1}(s-a)\right)+X^{\top} X a-X^{\top} y+\lambda_1 a\\
\\
0=&\gamma\left(X^{\top} X(s-a)+\lambda_{1}(s-a)\right)+X^{\top} X a-X^{\top} y+\lambda_1 a\\
\gamma\left(X^{\top} X(s-a)+\lambda_{1}(s-a)\right)=&X^{\top} y-X^{\top} X a-\lambda_1 a
\end{align}

However at this point I have 2 $d\times1$ matrices on each side of the equation and must take the inverse to get the answer. However this results in a 2x2 matrix and I am doubtful that a scalar can solve this. Can someone point out where I went wrong or what approach I should have taken to solve this?

Comment: If you want to optimize with respect to a and s, why don't you fill them in in the original equation and then take gradients? They will be different from what you do. The original equation only solves for beta in d*1 so you have d equations. To be on the line segment you have d unknowns for a and d unknowns for s so you need 2d equations.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough, I need to solve this for gamma. I have a and s already but want to know where on the line segment the optimal is.

Comment: Ah my bad, makes sense. But then you could still use my approach as you just set the derivative with respect to gamma to 0. Note that this is a derivative, not a gradient!

Answer (score 1):

As @Marekkk alluded to in his comment, the solution was to substitute the line segment into the main equation and find the derivative with respect to gamma.